# Xpather does not evaluate the XPath on firefox 3.5 but works fine on firefox 3.6

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces

I am working on a richface application and trying to evaluate the following xpath with xpather on firefox3.5. XPather does not evaluate any of the xpath though the same xpath works perfectly fine on firefox 3.6.
The page which I am testing is like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org">
  <head>
    <script src="some source" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="some source" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link class="component" href="some source" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link class="component" href="some source" 
          media="rich-extended-skinning" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link class="component" href="some source" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">window.RICH_FACES_EXTENDED_SKINNING_ON=true;</script>
    <link type="text/css" href="some source" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <body class="Banner" onresize="setTreePnlHeight()" onload="loadApp();">
    <input type="hidden" id="dsTreeScrollPos" value="0" />
    <div id="a" class="application"><form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="...">
    ....
  </body>
</html>
```

If I use xpather(v1.4.5) to evaluate the simple xpath on FF3.5 like `//input`, it does not return any result. Is namespace causing this issue? How can i verify my xpath on FF3.5?

Comment: How is the document served, as text/html or as text/xml or as application/xml or as application/xhtml+xml?

Comment: This document is served as text.html. content=text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Do you have a URL of a document where the problem occurs?

Comment: Sorry Martin, but the URL cannot be specified here :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> simple xpath on FF3.5 like `//input`, it
>   does not return any result. Is
>   namespace causing this issue?

Yes. If you look at your document, you have a default namespace definition there.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org">
```

This means that `//input` is looking for an element `<input>` without a namespace, whereas you should look for `<input>` that is in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace. You need to define that namespace and bind it to a prefix and then use that prefix in your XPath. like `//x:input`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.. but I am new to this. Could you please tell more about how can I define and bind the namespace to a prefix? I cannot modify the original document. I need to be able to get it working with XPather to test the application (and use this xpath with selenium).

Comment: I haven't used XPather so I cannot say does it have a specific procedure to manually registering namespaces. [XPather manual](http://xpath.alephzarro.com/documentation#xpathSettings) suggests that it uses same prefix what is defined in the document and prefix `default` for elements in default namespace (which are not prefixed). Therefore something like `//default:input` should work in your case. Quick googling seemed to gave hints that Selenium doesn't support namespaces, which would be a *huge* deficiency for XML processing.

Comment: @Santosh K: I Forgot to mention, there is also a commonly used workaround for selecting namespaced elements with a non-namespace aware tool: using a predicate and `local-name()` function. In this case `//input` would be written as `//*[local-name() = 'input']`

Comment: The workaround you suggested is working for me. The results are shown in Xpather by specifying predicate and local-name() function.